# Can't Resolve "child_process" in module xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a DataConnector class that is loading a JSON file.  Everything outside of this class is working perfectly fine in my app, so I don't think the issue is arrising anywhere else.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

//#File: DataConnector.js
var DataConnector = {};


DataConnector.LoadJSON = (function(file,callback) {   

    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log(xobj);
    xobj.open('GET', file, true); 
    xobj.overrideMimeType = "application/json";

    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {

                callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
    };
    xobj.send(null);  
})

DataConnector.getMessage = function(){
    return 'Hello DataConnector';
}



module.exports = DataConnector;
```

[image]
main.js

```
//#File: QuestionJS.js
//var $ = require('jquery');
Answer = require('./Answer');
Question = require('./Question');
ThemeGenerator = require('./ThemeGenerator');
DataConnector = require('./DataConnector')

//console.log(DataConnector.getMessage());
```

If I comment DataConnector out from being required, webpack is able to bundle my app perfectly fine.  I was also working on this earlier today on a different PC and it actualy worked perfectly fine every time.

I have used 
npm i -g xmlhttprequest
npm i xmlhttprequest
npm i xmlhttprequest --save

xmlhttprequest has files in the node_modules folder in my project folder and I am following the readme precisely.

I have honestly never been more confused, especially since this error never even showed up on the other system despite both being windows 10 systems with the save software installed.

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: Might need to share your webpack config, but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000827/webpack-and-typescript-cannot-resolve-module-child-process-in-node-d-ts

Answer (score 2):

The `xmlhttprequest` package is meant for *server-side* JavaScript. The `child_process` package is built into NodeJS. It is not an NPM package, so cannot be downloaded or included in any application outside of running on NodeJS. It is a package designed specifically for handling functionality internal to NodeJS.

It appears if you are trying to use the `xmlhttprequest` package on the front end. Since the `xmlhttprequest` package only works on NodeJS, you are receiving the error that `child_process` does not exist, because it does not exist in a front end browser. If that is the case, you may be pleased to know that [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is built into browsers. The reason the NodeJS package exists is to mimic the browser's innate functionality. You may be able to just remove the package as a whole and refer to the `XMLHttpRequest` class without error.

If you are working on code to support both back end and front end, you may result to something like this:

```
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest === 'undefined') {
  global.XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
}
```

If you are using Webpack to bundle a *back end* application, you may need to configure it to target `node` instead of a browser.

Comment: I suppose it’s possible that I’m doing it wrong, I’m trying to build a front end component, it’s a complex component that i was trying to modularize so that I could utilize OOP while building it.  I know that the browser has XMLHTTPRequest but I’m trying to bundle this file into a single file so that I can distribute it as a single component with easy set up.  Is there another way to use classes in JavaScript components?  I’m not sure why this would be an issue if it’s supported in both node and browsers.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is supported on the browser, because it's _built in_ to the browser. The package you are using is _not_ supported by the browser. It is supported by NodeJS on the _server_, because it is meant to provide the browser's built in XMLHttpRequest functionality to the server. Since you are not developing a server-side application, you do not need the package at all.